# Get Text outside of tags as well

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get some text out of a god-awful website.
This is the part where I'm stumped:

```
    <tr><td valign="top">
                    <br>
                    <b>AGFA&nbsp;ACCUSET,&nbsp;<i>1994</i></b>&nbsp;<font color=grey>(46965)</font><br>
                    <br>
                    <b>Equipements : </b><br>AGFA 9800<br>
WITH RIP VIPER N°2<br>
FILM PROCESSOR GLUNZ AND JENSEN ML35 n°26498<br>
(LAIZE 450/600mm)<br>
Spectraset 2200<br>
                    <b>Availability : </b>IMMEDIATE<br></td><tr>
```

What I need is all the text in there, so

> AGFA ACCUSET, 1994 (46965)
>
> Equipements : AGFA 9800
>
> WITH RIP VIPER N°2
>
> FILM PROCESSOR GLUNZ AND JENSEN ML35 n°26498
>
> (LAIZE 450/600mm)
>
> Spectraset 2200
>
> Availability : IMMEDIATE

As you can see, some of the text is inside `<b>`-tags and some is *in front* of `<br>`-tags. If I use soup.getText(), I get the Text outside of the tags, but I also get a lot of other text I don't want, so that doesn't really work.

**EDIT:** [This](http://agec.de/index.asp?a=1&lg=de&macnum=46965) is the link to the site in question.

**EDIT2:** Turned out I used the wrong parser. See below for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <tr><td valign="top">
...                     <br>
...                     <b>AGFA&nbsp;ACCUSET,&nbsp;<i>1994</i></b>&nbsp;<font color=grey>(46965)</font><br>
...                     <br>
...                     <b>Equipements : </b><br>AGFA 9800<br>
... WITH RIP VIPER N°2<br>
... FILM PROCESSOR GLUNZ AND JENSEN ML35 n°26498<br>
... (LAIZE 450/600mm)<br>
... Spectraset 2200<br>
...                     <b>Availability : </b>IMMEDIATE<br></td><tr>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> print(soup.tr.td.get_text())


AGFA ACCUSET, 1994 (46965)

Equipements : AGFA 9800
WITH RIP VIPER N°2
FILM PROCESSOR GLUNZ AND JENSEN ML35 n°26498
(LAIZE 450/600mm)

Spectraset 2200
Availability : IMMEDIATE
```

---

Here is the demo using the link you've shared with:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "http://agec.de/index.asp?a=1&lg=de&macnum=46965"
>>> 
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
>>> 
>>> soup.select('section#main_section aside#machine_detail form > table > tr')[1].get_text()


AGFA ACCUSET, 1994 (46965)

Equipements : AGFA 9800
WITH RIP VIPER N°2
FILM PROCESSOR GLUNZ AND JENSEN ML35 n°26498
(LAIZE 450/600mm)
Spectraset 2200
Availability : IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: I already tried something similar. Sadly, this result returns nothing. It's probably because of the weird way the site is built. Here is the [link](http://agec.de/index.asp?a=1&lg=de&macnum=46965) for the full page if you're interested to have a look. Be warned, though: it is ugly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Sadly, this still seems to return an empty object as I get an `IndexError: list index out of range`, even when I execute the exact same code step-for-step in the Python Interpreter.

Comment: @FreshPrince got it, this could be a separate problem due to differences between parsers bs uses under-the-hood. Try to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')` instead. Let me know if it helps or not.